# How to transpose my data from column to row based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently, I had been facing the problem on transpose data from column into row, however I know there got transpose function, but I need to transpose with my criteria. Sorry for my poor explanation, hopefully below draft you may understand.

[image]

And then we use these 2 column data and transpose into below picture shown.

[image]

Due to huge data and it might be more than 300k row data, so I hope to get a formula or a way to simplify and speedup the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I think `FILTER()` function may give you desired performance. First use `UNIQUE()` function to extract unique `drop_point` to row across. Then use Filter function to filter `awb no` as per `drop_point`.

```
 H1=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(E2:E12))
 H2=FILTER($A:$A,$E:$E=H1)
```

[image]

Comment: Well it might be good for lesser data cause I have over million row data that require longer time for counting